# Unable to open GUI in Ubuntu version 20.01, post installing XUbuntu using tasksel and rebooting the VM, tried Alt+Ctrl+F1 too but no luck

Tags: xubuntu, gui, reboot, lamp

Unable to open GUI in Ubuntu version 20.01, post installing XUbuntu using tasksel and rebooting the VM.
As per the vedio--> After Xubuntu was installed successfully--> reboot the system and GUI should be displayed
In my system, Xubuntu is installed successfully and post reboot --> GUI not displayed

Comment: Please clarify your release; there was no 2020-January (20.01) release; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format.